# is there a makeActiveBinding for subsets?

Tags: r, reactive-programming

The following shows what I would like:

```
session <- data.frame(period=rep(1:2, each=3), id=rep(1:3,2), x=NA)
makeActiveBinding("subject", function (x) {
  session[session$period==period & session$id==id,]
}, environment())

period <- 2
id <- 1
subject
##     period id  x
##   4      2  1 NA
id <- 2
subject
##     period id  x
##   5      2  2 NA
```

Fine so far!
But:

```
subject$x <- "id 2 did sthg"
subject
##   period id  x
##   5      2  2 NA
```

Is there any way to bind object subsetting? Perhaps there is something obvious I'm missing...

Answer (score 0):

tumbleweed!

Subsetting works by copying the whole object and then assigning to it. As a result, the following would work:

```
session <- data.frame(period=rep(1:2, each=3), id=rep(1:3,2), x=NA)
makeActiveBinding("subject", function (x) {
  if (missing(x)) {
    session[session$period==period & session$id==id,]
  } else {
    session[session$period==period & session$id==id,] <<- x
  }
}, environment())
```

The use of the global assignment operator (`<<-`) is important, otherwise you only assign in the environment of the function.